# insert into an existing attribute in json with angular (nested json)

Tags: angularjs, json, nested

So in my application I have small blocks of info called *suntis*.  Each sunti can have .tags, .author, .ancestor, .short_id, and some other attributes.

Say I have a sunti with the following

```
sunti_one = {
    content: "The nature of mankind is deep-down inseparable from the nature of the cosmos",
    tags: "philosophy, cosmos, nature, man",
    ancestor: "none",
    short_id: "H18EIQ5p"
}
```

Then I have a sunti with the following, where the ancestor field points to the short_id of the above sunti:

```
sunti_two = {
    content: "It's true that man and the cosmos are entertwined, but man is clearly embedded in the cosmos.  Yet, does that mean necessarily that the cosmos is embedded in man, too?"
    tags: "cosmos, entertwined, man, question"
    ancestor: "H18EIQ5p", << right here
    short_id: BkwV9q2a  
}
```

I want to check incoming suntis to see if they have an ancestor_id that exists already in my stash/cache of suntis-seen-so-far.

Now I have something like

```
socket.on('load_sunti_from_cache', function(a_sunti_over_the_wire) {

        angular.forEach($scope.suntis, function(single_sunti_in_stash) {

            //check stash'd sunti short_ids against incoming ancestor_ids
            //console.log(a_sunti_over_the_wire.ancestor + " \\\ over wire")
            //console.log(single_sunti_in_stash.short_id + " /// sunti stash")

            if (a_sunti_over_the_wire.ancestor == single_sunti_in_stash.short_id) {
                console.log('Matching ancestor & short_id: ' + single_sunti_in_stash.short_id)
                $scope.suntis. ...? (what do I put here so that the over_the_wire sunti gets appended as a descendent of the matching ancestor sunti?)
            }
        })
```

I want the result to be:

```
{
        content: "The nature of mankind is deep-down inseparable from the nature of the cosmos",
        tags: "philosophy, cosmos, nature, man",
        ancestor: "none",
        short_id: "H18EIQ5p",
        descendents: {
                      {
                      content: "It's true that man and the cosmos are entertwined, but man is clearly embedded in the cosmos.  Yet, does that mean necessarily that the cosmos is embedded in man, too?"
                      tags: "cosmos, entertwined, man, question"
                      ancestor: "H18EIQ5p"
                      short_id: BkwV9q2a  
                      }
                     }
 }
```

Comment: what is the specific problem or question?

Comment: Well I am solving this using Two (json) arrays now, $scope.suntis and $scope.sunti_descendents, but I originally wanted to have nested JSON.  I get a new sunti; check if it has an ancestor already in my sunti array, and if it does, add it as a nested json object.  My question is how to add nested json via angular.

Comment: descendants needs to be array...push into array as needed. would be a lot simpler if you had a `parentId` in the child elements

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you charlie, if you could post an answer saying the same I would gladly accept it.  I had to check if there was a descendents property, if not then create an empty descendents array `$scope.suntis[sunti_stash_index].descendents = []` and push into it as you said.